# Simple Python Unit Testing With Test Cases In Multiple Folders

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am new to unit testing using python and am designing a simple unit test setup. This is what I have made:

```
/python_test
    __init__.py
    unittest_main.py
    test_abc/
        __init__.py
        test_abc.py    
    test_pqr/
        __init__.py
        test_pqr.py
```

All the __init__.py files are empty and the other files have some basic content:

**unittest_main.py**

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import inspect
import unittest
from sets import Set

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    testCases = glob.glob('test_*')
    testTargets = Set([])
    for testTarget in sys.argv:
        if testTarget == "test_all":
            testTargets = testCases
            break
        else:
            for testCase in testCases:
                if testCase == testTarget:
                    testTargets.add(testCase)
                    break
    if len(testTargets) > 0:
        print testTargets
        suiteList = []
        for testTarget in testTargets:
            cmd_subfolder =    os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.split(inspect.getfile( inspect.currentframe() ))[0],testTarget)))
            if cmd_subfolder not in sys.path:
                sys.path.insert(0, cmd_subfolder)
            suiteList.append(unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromModule("python_test"+"."+testTarget+"."+testTarget))
        mainSuite = unittest.TestSuite(suiteList)
        unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1).run(mainSuite)
    else:
        "No Proper Test Targets Specified"
else:
    print "No Test Targets Specified"
```

**test_abc.py**

```
import unittest

class test_abc(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print "Setup Complete"

    def tearDown(self):
        print "Tear Down Complete"

    def test_abc_main(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 2, "test-abc Failure")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

**test_pqr.py**

```
import unittest

class test_pqr(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print "Setup Complete"

    def tearDown(self):
        print "Tear Down Complete"

    def test_abc_main(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 2, "test-pqr Failure")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

**Question:**

I am able to test the test cases separately but when I use the parent directly file to run all the tests, nothing happens?

```
$ ~/src/python_test$ python unittest_main.py test_all
['test_pqr', 'test_abc']

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

The installed Python Version is 2.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're passing module names to the loader, you want to use `loadTestsFromName` instead of `loadTestsFromModule`.

Comment: Thanks @ddelemeny! Yes that solved it. I was also passing the folder name as part of the module name which I removed too. This made it work:  suiteList.append(unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromName(testTarget+"."+testTarget))